# I am not commenting for you vs I am not commenting about you

Tags: difference

> I am not commenting for you
>
> I am not commenting about you

Someone was *talking crap* on my Facebook comments when I asked him why he was doing that. He said **“I am not commenting for you”**

Shouldn't he have said **about you**?

Answer (score 2):

They mean different things, assuming the writer knew what they were saying.

> I am not commenting for you

-> My comments are not for your benefit. You aren't the intended audience. The comments are directed at other people, for their entertainment.

> I am not commenting about you

-> Like you mentioned, if the comments were *about* you or not.